# The logo image is not getting displayed in the header

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code for the header in React

```
 <img
    className="app__headerImage"
    src="../img/instalogo.jpg"
    alt=""
    />
```

But somehow the image path is not detected. Please suggest a solution if you have any.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import image to react in below format

```
import img from '../image/instalogo.jpg'
```

Then put the same in attribute in below format

```
<img
    className="app__headerImage"
    src={img}
    alt=""
    />
```

Comment: Hi..If this resolved your query pls mark this as answer for future reader

Comment: and try posting your css too.. cause, maybe somewhere you just moved that out of screen.. try inspecting ..